# How to delete all files in ~/Downloads that have not been touched, added, or opened in the last 30 days?

Tags: bash, macos, automator

I'm trying to create an automator workflow or application that, when activated, deletes all the files and subfolders in my Downloads folder that have not been created, modified, added, opened, or accessed in any way in the last 30 days.

I tried filtering like this:

[image: screenshot of automator]

But that doesn't really do the job like I want it. First of all, there's no option to filter by "date added", which I would really like. Secondly, I would prefer it to prioritize a subfolder over that subfolder's contents. For example, I have a folder which I added today, but the file inside that folder has a "date added" of much longer ago. My preference would be that that folder, including its contents, are ignored and therefor **not** deleted.

[image: screenshot of dates of example folder and files]

Then I read in another Stack Overflow thread (or it was at least some Stack Exchange site) that someone recommended to use a bash script instead. Something like this for example:

```bash
$ find "$HOME/Downloads" -type fd -mtime +30d -atime +30d -iname '*.*'
```

But even that doesn't seem to filter out the exact items that I want to filter out.

So just to be clear, I want to delete everything in my Downloads folder that has not been added, opened, created or modified in the last 30 days. And if there's any subtree where *any* of the folders or files within that subtree *has* been added, opened, created or modified within the last 30 days, then I would like that entire subtree to be ignored and left alone. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: You can do what you are doing, but your syntax is wrong. Problem is you don't have fine control over the time period. `-mtime` measures time from the beginning of today, so the number of hours between then and now are not taken into account. Tu use your command, which may be "close enough", you would do `find ~/Downloads -mtime 29 -atime 29` (you can add `-delete` after you confirm the list is what you want). For files/directories not accessed in 30 days, you need `29` - 24-hour periods from the beginning of today. (see my answer for finer control over the time-part)

Comment: Did you ever found solution for Automator usage? Having similar experience so it doesn't give relevant results. Same happens even if "Date last modified" is used with "is not in the last" condition, it still can return file which is created/modified today

Comment: Yes, I've come across that problem and I didn't know how to solve it, so in the end I disabled my script, unfortunately... Maybe I'll open a new question, so see if someone knows how to fix this...

Answer (score 2):

This is another approach if you don't want to use find. Works with folders, files. comment out the `rm -rf` to confirm.

```
#!/bin/bash
compareDate=$(date -d "30 days ago" '+%Y%m%d')
for f in ~/Downloads/*;
do
    fileDate=$(date -r "$f" -u "+%Y%m%d")
    if [ ! "$fileDate" -gt "$compareDate" ];then
        echo Deleting - "$f";
        rm -rf  "$f"
    else 
        echo Keeping - "$f"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so with `find` and the `-newerXY` option (which you negate) where `XY` is equal to `mt` for modification time, `at` for access time and `ct` for creation time. You simply pass `-delete` to remove the matching filenames. You can do:

```sh
d=$(date -d "30 days ago" '+%F %T')     # get date and time 30 days ago
find ~/Downloads -type f ! -newermt "$d" ! -newerat "$d" ! -newerct "$d" -delete
```

(the order of the options is important as they are evaluated as an expression, if you put `-delete` first it will delete all files under the `~/Download` path as there is nothing to modify the list of files before `-delete` is encountered)

**Note:** test without `-delete` to make sure it returns the list you expect it to and then add the option back in to actually remove the files.

---

**Thoughts On Change of Question to If Any File is Newer in Mod, Access or Change -- Keep all in that Directory**

After your edit, where any one file in a subdirectory will prevent removal of any files in the subdirectory, that will prevent a single call to `find` from being helpful since `find` processes a single file at a time without knowledge of how tests on other files went.

Here my thought is more to loop over the directories under `~/Downloads` one at a time relying on `globstar` being set. You will change to your `"$HOME"` directory (in the script) so the paths generated by the `**/` search will be relative to `"$HOME"` without extraneous other path components for `/home/user` prepended to them.

Create a short function that loops over each file in the directory being processed, and if any one file is newer in modification, access or change, do nothing with that directory, all files are save.

A quick implementation using `stat` to using date and mod, access and change times in seconds since epoch, you could do:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar     # endable globstar globbing

dt=$(date -d "30 days ago" '+%s')   # 30 days ago in seconds since epoch

cd "$HOME" || exit 1  # change to home directory path globbing to Downloads
dld="Downloads"       # set Downloads varabile 

# function returns 0 if no files in dir with access or mod time in 30 days
# returns 1 otherwise (don't remove)
nonenewerthan30 () {
  local dir="$1"
  [ -d "$dir" ] || return 1   # validate it is a dir
  for f in "$dir"/*; do       # loop over files in dir
    [ -d "$f" ] && continue   # skip any directories in dir
    [ $(stat -c %X "$f") -gt "$dt" ] && return 1  # mod time since epoch
    [ $(stat -c %Y "$f") -gt "$dt" ] && return 1  # access time since epoch
    [ $(stat -c %Z "$f") -gt "$dt" ] && return 1  # change time since epoch
  done
  
  return 0    # directory can be removed.
}


for d in "$dld"/**/; do               # loop Downloads and all subdirs
  d="${d%/}"                          # remove trailing '/'
  [ "$d" = "$dld" ] && continue       # skip Downloads until subs processed
  printf "\nprocessing: %s\n" "$d"
  nonenewerthan30 "$d" && {           # call func, on 0 return, remove sub
    echo "  can remove $d"
    # rm -r "$d"           # uncomment after your verify behavior
  }
done
```

Currently it skips processing the files in `Downloads` until all the subdirectories are done. You will need to keep track if files are retained at any level to know whether or not removing them from `Downloads` is even an options. Adding that logic I leave to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I test it, I can see that the list still contains a file that is indeed older than 30 days, however, the folder above that file has a "Date Added" of today, so I'd prefer that file to be left alone. Do you know any way to do that? I have a hunch that I'd need to use two different commands, one command that selects too many files and then one command that then uses the output from the first command and filters out the wrong results. I'm currently experimenting with mdfind to see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. Since the `-type f` limits the `find` to files only (you can remove `-type` and it defaults to all files/directories), so your list based on the command above should only contain files that are more than 30 days in mtime, atime, and ctime.. Adjoining expressions (e.g. `! newermt ... ! newerat ...` are AND'ed together, so the files selected would have to pass all 3 conditions. So if "Date Added" (`ctime`) is today, it should not be included. Hold on and I'll give you a test to run on that file so we can make sure.

Comment: What does `ls -l file` show? (mtime) and what does `ls -cl file` show? (ctime) and lastly `ls -ul file` (for atime)? That will at least let us see what the filesystem thinks all 3 timestamps are. You can use `stat file` to see all 3 timestamps simultaneously.

Comment: Okay, I got your edit and now understand your comment better based on the edit. `find` provides a *Per-File* test and does not aggregate conditions based on other file timestamps. What you want to do is doable, but not with a single call to `find`. Here, you would have to take each directory and subdirectory and iterate over the files to find the last modified, created and accessed file, and then only is that file is also more than 30 days old in each criteria, would you remove the files in that subtree. That's something you can do looping over the directories one at a time.

Comment: I haven't tried your script yet, maybe your script does exactly what I want. But I have a feeling that maybe it can be done with just 2 lines of code. The first one being this: `mdfind -onlyin "$HOME/Downloads" '(kMDItemDateAdded > $time.today(-1M) || kMDItemLastUsedDate > $time.today(-1M) && kMDItemContentCreationDate > $time.today(-1M) || kMDItemFSContentChangeDate > $time.today(-1M))' | grep -E 'Downloads/[^/]+$'`. It lists all the root files that are younger than 30 days, and all the subfolders where any subfile or subfolder is younger than 30 days.

Comment: So now I just need to create a second command that literally lists *all* the files and folders in Downloads, and then subtract any item from that list which path begins with any item of the previous list. And then I'll have the correct list of files and folders I want to delete, I think. What do you think?

Comment: Okay, I found the command that lists all the files I want to delete. It's big and messy, but here it is: `find ~/Downloads | grep -vE "^$HOME/Downloads$|^$(mdfind -onlyin ~/Downloads '(kMDItemDateAdded > $time.today(-1M) || kMDItemLastUsedDate > $time.today(-1M) || kMDItemContentCreationDate > $time.today(-1M) || kMDItemFSContentChangeDate > $time.today(-1M))' | grep -E 'Downloads/[^/]+$' | tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/|/|^/g' | sed 's/\./\\./g' | sed 's/|^$//g' | sed -e 's/\$/\\$/g' | sed -e 's/[(]/\\(/g' | sed -e 's/[)]/\\)/g')"` Now I just need to figure out how to delete each item in this list.

Comment: Just pipe the result to `xargs rm -r`, so `your_long_command | xargs rm -r` (if for some really strange reason your `xargs` isn't in your default PATH, you can use `/bin/xargs` instead) Note: long pipelines can be slow (may not be an issue in your case), but above you spawn `11` subshells tied together with `10` pipes (`12` and `11` when you add `xargs`). That's running `11+` programs to accomplish the task. Almost worth writing in C at that point.